# Explaining hashcode to Vector

Tags: java, collections, vector, hashcode, java-6

Can I get an idea of how the hashcode takes the valueas per the element added to vector?

```
  Vector v = new Vector();

  //Add elements to Vector
  v.add("1");
  System.out.println(v.hashCode());
  v.add("2");
  System.out.println(v.hashCode());
  v.add("=");
  System.out.println(v.hashCode());
```

The hashcode values are

```
 80
 2530
 78491
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the same for every (true) implementation of the List interface (if it supports adding elements). The behavior of the `.hashCode` method is defined in [`List.hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29) as follows:

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
>  int hashCode = 1;
>  Iterator<E> i = list.iterator();
>  while (i.hasNext()) {
>      E obj = i.next();
>      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
>  }
> ```
>
> This ensures that `list1.equals(list2)` implies that `list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode()` for any two lists,
>   `list1` and `list2`, as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode()`.

As glowcoder showed, `AbstractList` contains just this implementation, and thus not every implementor of the `List` interface has to do this again.

For example, you also could write `Arrays.asList("1", "2").hashCode()` and would get the same 2530 (as long as you don't change the `hashCode()` implementation of `String`).

Answer (score 2):

Because Vector extends AbstractList, it uses it for it's hashCode. Here's what it does.

```
public int hashCode() {
int hashCode = 1;
Iterator<E> i = iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    E obj = i.next();
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
}
return hashCode;
}
```

Comment: See also [Hashing it out](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html).